# How do I get my basket notification to only be shown if 1 or more items are in the cart?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a call for the total price of the users cart to appear in the header but I only want it to be shown if there are 1 or more items in the users cart. Does anyone know what I need to add to the code to do this? I have tried a few suggestions I've found online but none has worked.

This is my current HTML code (that doesn't work):

```
     <?php if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) { ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/cart">
            <div id=basket>
                <span class="tot-price"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span>
                <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-shopping-cart"></span>
            </div>
        </a>    }
    <?php
    endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does $cart_contents_count return? Does it return anything?

Comment: I don't really know the answer to that sorry. I'm here because I need the help. @David.J

Comment: If you add <?php echo $cart_contents_count; ?> before the if statement, you should see. You may need to call the global woo variable.

Comment: What would calling the global woo variable entail.. I'm literally asking for the code to be spelled out.

Comment: It's this: global $woocommerce;  That should be added to the start of your php. Maybe add a bit more code for context

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the if statement you can use if statement like this

```
if(CONDITION){

}
```

or like this

```
if ($value):

endif;
```

Use 1st case if you are using php only
And 2nd if you want to insert html content in between it

Your code contain

```
<?php if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) { ?>
```

as start and

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this for end which wrong. Use like this

```
    <?php if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) : ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/cart">
            <div id=basket>
                <span class="tot-price"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span>
                <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-shopping-cart"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work. It does however make my the cart total disappear.

Comment: can you print `$cart_contents_count` to make sure that is is greater then 0 as your condition says